# Create several buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

I want to create 10 buttons in the `ViewController`. These buttons move the user to the next `ViewController`. If I use a storyboard, do I have to create 10 buttons or is there an easier way to solve the problem?

It should also satisfy following conditions:

- my button into cell won't be gray or another colour. But I need to my button will be selected and change colour.
- If I use the tableView and press the button, the selected cell fills up with a gray color. I want to select only the button. (Tableview should not show gray color for selection)

Comment: Do you want to have some special grid? You can create these buttons in code.

Comment: you can use UIColletionView or UITableview , you need to decide which fits you best

Comment: @Phyber I know, But I want to use auto layout for different screens

Comment: You can use the auto layout in code too.

Comment: As @Dev_Tandel mentioned you can use UICollectionView, UITableView or you can use UIStackView.

Comment: Can you show us how your screen with 10 buttons should look like?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel When I use the tableView and press the button, the selected cell fills up with a gray color. I want to select only the button. Is there such a problem in ColletionView?

Comment: @Phyber - Thank you.. but for UIstackView we need to place 10 buttons , i think he wants to avoid that. But Thanx you for the mention, He have one more option to consider.

Comment: You can solve your problem with tableview like this: `cell.selectionStyle = .none` inside cellForRowAt

Comment: @user -  You can avoid that. Select your cell and change selection to none from default. You must select cell not your tableview and do the above

Comment: @Dev_Tandel If I change the selection to "none", the cell will not be selected, but my button will also not be selected

Comment: @user Check my comment. By using that code your cell won't be gray but still, you will be able to select it.

Comment: @Phyber buttons like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF1XR.png or this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-OjJlyHvV6y8/Voufi-KK3SI/AAAAAAAAOKQ/kOLqRuBUmQU/s1600/UIStackView%2Band%2BUIButton.jpg

Comment: @Phyber Of course my cell won't be gray but still, and can I select it. But in this case my button into cell won't be gray or another colour. But I need to my button will be selected and change colour

Comment: @user - As i told dont select you tableview , select cell and in property change selection style to None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code as solution to your problem (it's working according to your requirement, just copy and paste in your view controller)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tblTable: UITableView!

    var buttonTitles = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblTable.delegate = self
        tblTable.dataSource = self
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buttonTitles.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "buttoncell") as! ButtonCell

      let buttonTitle: String = buttonTitles[indexPath.row]
      cell.btnButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
      cell.btnButton.tag = indexPath.row
      cell.btnButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClick(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
      cell.selectionStyle = .none
      return cell
   }

   @objc func buttonClick(button: UIButton) -> Void {
    print("btnButton clicked at index - \(button.tag)")
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected

    if button.isSelected {
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
  }

}


class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var btnButton: UIButton!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if selected {
            btnButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            btnButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }

    }

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

        if highlighted {
            btnButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            btnButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }
    }
}
```

And Snapshot of storyboard layout with tableview and cell interface design

[image]

Here is result (working behavior of button) in simulator

[image]

I think, this is enough to solve your problem.

Comment: It works. But I want to use segue to move to the next controller. How to use segue, which goes to the next controller when the button is pressed?

Comment: I ask question, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739295/swift-segue-on-button-click